# Thread in micropython Raspberry Pi Pico W does not activate

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I was following the previous example:

`

```
"""
Basic multi thread example
"""
 
from time import sleep
import _thread
 
 
def core0_thread():
    counter = 0
    while True:
        print(counter)
        counter += 2
        sleep(1)
 
 
def core1_thread():
    counter = 1
    while True:
        print(counter)
        counter += 2
        sleep(2)
 
 
second_thread = _thread.start_new_thread(core1_thread, ())
 
core0_thread()`
```

In my case I want to run the web server listener, along with an environment control system in a separate class by calling a method in another class: box.start_control_box()

I define it like this:

```
def start_control_box(self):
    count = 0
    while True:
        if self.temperature > 20:
            self.overheat_alarm()
        elif self.humidity > 80:
            self.overhumidity_alarm()
        elif self.temperature < 20:
            self.cold_alarm()
        elif self.humidity < 60:
            self.low_humidity_alarm()
        time.sleep(10)`
```

and I call it from the main class main.py like this:

```
import machine
import time
from class_Box import Box
import _thread

led_pin = machine.Pin("LED", machine.Pin.OUT)

box = Box()

box_thread = _thread.start_new_thread(box.start_control_box, ())

while True:
    led_pin.toggle()
    time.sleep(1)`
```

After this, I don't have any response from the microcontroller and I can't connect to the Raspberry Pi Pico w microcontroller again using Thonny or PyCharm. However, the device appears connected in Ubuntu:

$ ls /dev/

crw-rw----  1 root    dialout 166,   0 dic 14 12:51 ttyACM0

I want, using the _thread module, to start sensor monitoring (box.start_control_box) and at the same time start a Raspberry Pi Pico W web server and listen for the web page actions listener to be activated.

If it is not possible, I would like to know what error I have in using the _thread module in my example.

Thanks in advance.

To correct the problem I have tried three solutions:

1. I have connected and disconnected the Raspberry Pi Pico W several times, looking for a restart that would allow me to access the device through Thonny.
2. I put the monitoring start class box.start_control_box, in the main class main.py. I get the same error.
3. I added the parentheses thinking I could add the function to the _thread call like this:

box_thread = _thread.start_new_thread(box.start_control_box(), ())

It makes a normal call to a function, but does not execute it as a thread.

Comment: You have code to toggle a pin named "LED".  Is there a physical LED connected?  If so, does it toggle once per second?